# maintain value of textarea in jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery Datatables and I have a textarea in one column as described at
http://www.datatables.net/

The value entered in the textarea is lost when I click on sort in the column header.
I did following so far to maintain the value in dtSetup. But the blur event is not working.

```
 $('#dtSetup input[type=text]').blur(function() {

    txtMessageArr.push([this.id, this.val() ]);


    });

'fnDrawCallback': function() {
    var oTable = $('#dtSetup').dataTable();

    $('input[type=textarea]', oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){
                                    if($.inArray(this.id, txtMessageArr)>=0)
                                            this.value = txtMessageArr[$.inArray(this.id, txtMessageArr)][0];
                                    });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Textarea` is another tag and not an `input` tag, try this

```
var txtMessageArr = [];

$('#dtSetup textarea').blur(function() {

    txtMessageArr.push([this.id, $(this).html()]);

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work either  $('#dtSetup textarea').blur(function() {

    alert('hi')

});  Not sure what event is needed.

Comment: because textarea is a tag with innerhtml, not an input with value, use this.html() instead of this.val()

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
var txtMessageArr = [];

$('#dtSetup textarea').live('blur',function() {

    txtMessageArr.push([this.id, this.val() ]);

});
```

When the datatable date is reloaded, all the events attached to is lost. Using live means, it will apply it to all current and future elements matching the selector!

Comment: thanks but blur did not work for me.  live('focusout',function()) worked and jquery site says: The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus from parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Comment: nice that it worked for you, apart from all, `live()` is the thing you should use in such cases as all events are lost, if elements itself is lost, `live()` handles such situations